# VBA recursive function get data only from new files.

Tags: excel, vba

Im using recursive function for getting specific data from files in folders and subfolders on my disk. This data are saved as a new row in my excel file and create the table. It works fine. But if I create new file and put it into random subfolder, after starting the recursive function, I want to add that data as new row in my table that was created before. Instead of removing whole table and then repeatedly start recursive function and get data in the table.

Something like refresh button - if I click on it, it will check every folder and subfolder and if find some new file or files, add them on the last row in the table.

This is the code I´m using now:

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Folder
Dim mySubFolder As Folder
Dim myFile As File
Dim erow
Dim Black
Dim cislokabla

Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files


  erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

GetData myFile, "Sheet1", _
"F1:F2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1)), True, False

Black = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

GetData myFile, "Sheet1", _
"O4:O5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Black, 2), Cells(Black, 2)), True, False

cislokabla = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

GetData myFile, "Sheet1", _
"AH1:AH2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Black, 3), Cells(Black, 3)), True, False






    Next
    Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)
Next

End Function

Sub nacitavaniedat()

Call Recurse("\\Sk-wftkabel\public\Identifikačné listy káblov\káble\")


End Sub
```

Comment: There are two possible solution I have in mind with some problems to consider. **First- based on time the file was saved.** Store information when you called your sub last time. Run it again and check `If FileDataTime(myFile)>LastRunTime Then...add new data`. Problem here- if `myFile` was saved again it will have new `FileDataTime` and will be attached again. **Second- based on file list.** Keep in separate sheet the list of all files you already processed and before adding new data just check if file isn't already on the list. Problems here- additional operation and sheet to keep files name.

Comment: You need to implement some logic to compare already existing *rows* with ones you're attempting to add to the table. Find a unique factor (+1 to KazJaw for date and time approach, you could serialize your data based on this). Nobody will write this for you unless you try it yourself and come back and tell us where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need sheet2 named "Sheet2" to store filenames :)
(changed 30.01.14)

```
  Sub Recurse()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder, mySubFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim myFile As File
Dim sPath$: sPath = "\\Sk-wftkabel\public\Identifikacne listy kablov\kable\"
Dim R$
R = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange), "|")
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
        DoEvents
        If Not (InStr(1, R, myFile.Path) > 0) Then
            GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "F1:F2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)), True, False
            GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "O4:O5", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)), True, False
            GetData myFile, "Sheet1", "AH1:AH2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 3)), True, False
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = myFile.Path
            R = R & myFile.Path & "|"
        End If
    Next
Next
Set FSO = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set mySubFolder = Nothing
Set myFile = Nothing
End Sub

Option Explicit


Public Sub GetData(SourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
               SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, Header As Boolean,
               UseHeaderRow As Boolean)

' 30-Dec-2007, working in Excel 2000-2007
Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long

' Create the connection string.
If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & SourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    ' workbook level name
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    ' worksheet level name or range
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$" & SourceRange$ & "];"
End If

On Error GoTo SomethingWrong

Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1

' Check to make sure we received data and copy the data
If Not rsData.EOF Then

    If Header = False Then
        TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        'Add the header cell in each column if the last argument is True
        If UseHeaderRow Then
            For lCount = 0 To rsData.Fields.Count - 1
                TargetRange.Cells(1, 1 + lCount).Value = _
                rsData.Fields(lCount).Name
            Next lCount
            TargetRange.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Else
            TargetRange.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
        End If
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No records returned from : " & SourceFile, vbCritical
End If

' Clean up our Recordset object.
rsData.Close
Set rsData = Nothing
rsCon.Close
Set rsCon = Nothing
Exit Sub

SomethingWrong:
MsgBox "The file name, Sheet name or Range is invalid of : " & SourceFile, _
       vbExclamation, "Error"
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks great but it doesnt work. It only gets data from first found folder and on the sheet2 add path only from first found file.

Comment: try as it was: `Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject` and remove `Set FSO = New FileSystemObject`

Comment: it is the same thing.

Comment: oh, typo. should be `R = R & myFile.Path & "|"` not `R = R & myFile.ParentFolder & "|"`

Comment: edited answer code, but can't test since i don't have GetData function. Also "cislokabla" variable weren't used, so i fixed this.

Comment: Also edited answer code.It is not working ( type mismatch run-time error ) so I add the GetData function for testing. Thanks.

Comment: add 1 to cells A1 A2 on Sheet2. and i changed code a little more. should work.

Comment: it gets run-time error 76 (path not found) and after debuging it marks this line Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath). I check the path and it´s set correct.

Comment: it only means that path is incorrect. try to copy directly from explorer to code. maybe some charachters looks same but it's not.